# PHP & Xpath: Get All The First Level HTML Tags (All Siblings)

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath, domdocument

My functions needs to get all the first level HTML tags from a portion of HTML code so I can then work with each.

This is my HTML document summarized here:

```
<p>The breed was first...</p>
<p>Semencic credits his...</p>

<h1>Appearance</h1>
<p>The breed's distinctive...</p>
<p>It should be symmetrical...</p>

<figure id="attachment_6" style="width: 840px" class="wp-caption alignnone">
    <img class="size-large wp-image-6" src="...jpg" alt="boerboel appearance" width="840" height="746">
    <figcaption class="wp-caption-text">The dog appearance.</figcaption>
</figure>

<h1>Requirements</h1>
<p>Prospective owners....</p>
<p>These dogs....</p>

<h2>A Little Warning!</h2>
<p>If you are considering...</p>
<blockquote>
    <p>According to...</p>
    <p>Source: http://...</p>
</blockquote>
<p>Although more suitable...</p>
```

Now, I want my output to be:

```
p
p
h1
p
p
figure
h1
p
p
h2
p
blockquote
p
```

But right now, it is:

```
h1
p
h1
p
h2
p
blockquote
p
```

There are several things wrong:
- the 'figure' isn't showing
- the paragraph tags are singled out even when there are several siblings
- the first p's aren't found

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML( $this->post_content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD );

$xpath = new DOMXpath( $doc );
$nodes = $xpath->query( "/*/*" );

foreach ( $nodes as $node ) {

    echo $node->nodeName;
    echo '<br>';

    $this->add_part(
        md5( $node->textContent ),
        $node->nodeName
    );
}
```

Comment: I think you have to post the real HTML code. Your code works for me, using your HTML sample wrapped by a tag.

Comment: my html code is the real html code, there is no tag wrapping all of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOM (libxml) will reformat the input so that it has a single document element. If you remove the parser options (`LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD`) it will repair the html and add `html` and `body` elements. So if you want the element nodes inside `body` you can use the expression `//body/*`

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//body/*') as $node) {
  var_dump($node->nodeName);
}
```

Output:

```
string(1) "p"
string(1) "p"
string(2) "h1"
string(1) "p"
string(1) "p"
string(6) "figure"
string(2) "h1"
string(1) "p"
string(1) "p"
string(2) "h2"
string(1) "p"
string(10) "blockquote"
string(1) "p"
```

Answer (score 0):

For the records: with your precise HTML sample, I obtain this result:

```
p / h1 / p / p / figure / h1 / p / p / h2 / p / blockquote / p
```

instead of this (as per your question):

```
    h1 / p /              h1 / p /     h2 / p / blockquote / p
```

<kbd>**[3v4l.org demo](https://3v4l.org/bRekq)**</kbd>

So, I don't know if this answer will resolve your issue in real code.

---

HTML has some rules. You try to process a code without root element. Wrap your code by something like `<body>`:

```
$doc->loadHTML( "<body>$txt</body>", LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD );
```

By this way, I obtain your desired result:

```
p
p
h1
p
p
figure
h1
p
p
h2
p
blockquote
p
```

<kbd>**[3v4l.org demo](https://3v4l.org/NCP9e)**</kbd>

Comment: If this solution doesn't work, can you please print `->post_content` and show us the result ( copying it from page source, not from rendered page or inspector )?